# Cannot pickle output of `re.finditer` in Python

Tags: python, pickle, python-re

I am having problems to pickle the output of `re.finditer` outputs.

Here is a MWE:

```
import re
import pickle

s = 'Hi my name is John'

out = re.finditer('John',s)
pickle.dump(out, open('re.pkl','wb'))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_sre.SRE_Scanner' object
```

Any idea how to save this object?
I also have no luck using `pickle.dump(list(out), open('re.pkl','wb'))`

The error this time is

```
 TypeError: cannot pickle 're.Match' object
```

I am using Python 3.8.3

Answer (score 4):

Because you get an iterator which iterates over *match objects*, match objects does not have a `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` thus cannot be pickled, the entire iterator could not be pickled.

More about this subject can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable

Here is a further explanation on the desired objects:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Example use of pickle with match objects:

```
import re
import pickle

s = 'Hi my name is John'
matches = []
out = re.finditer('John', s)
for m in out:
    matches.append((m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))
pickle.dump(matches, open('re.pkl', 'wb'))
```

an alternative solution is to implement `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` to help the pickling process, this will require you to create a custom class and implement this function, which seem too overcomplicated for this situation.